# Could not save point cloud map from rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, 3d-slam, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I tried to generate a 3D mapping using fetch in gazebo simulation using rtabmap, and I was able to open the rtabmap.db file. Although I could see the map when I open the file with "rtabmap ~/.ros/rtabmap.db," I cannot export as ply. The error is:

```
Could create clouds for 104 node(s). You may want to activate clouds regeneration option.
```

When I check the regeneration option in the export console, the error becomes:

```
Could not create clouds for 188 node(s). The cache may not contain point cloud data. Try re-downloading the map.
```

The launch file I used for mapping is:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Kinect cloud to laser scan -->
<node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
  <remap from="image"       to="/head_camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
  <remap from="camera_info" to="/head_camera/depth_registered/camera_info"/>
  <remap from="scan"        to="/base_scan"/>
  <param name="range_max" type="double" value="4"/>
</node>

   <!-- SLAM -->
 <group ns="rtabmap">
<node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link"/>

      <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool" value="true"/>

      <remap from="odom" to="/odom"/>
      <remap from="scan_cloud" to="/head_camera/depth_registered/points"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/head_camera/rgb/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="/head_camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/head_camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

      <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>

      <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
      <param name="RGBD/ProximityBySpace"     type="string" value="false"/>
      <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate"        type="string" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate"         type="string" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="false"/>
      <param name="Reg/Force3DoF"             type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="Vis/MinInliers"            type="string" value="12"/>
</node>

<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd_gui.ini" output="screen">
  <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="false"/>
  <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <param name="frame_id"           type="string" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="wait_for_transform" type="bool" value="true"/>

  <remap from="odom" to="/odom"/>
  <remap from="scan_cloud" to="/head_camera/depth_registered/points"/>
  <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/head_camera/rgb/image_raw"/>
  <remap from="depth/image"     to="/head_camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
  <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/head_camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

</node>

</group>
</launch>
```

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343312/could-not-save-point-cloud-map-from-rtabmap/) by [JeffHu7](https://answers.ros.org/users/39986/jeffhu7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the map is totally empty, maybe the depth images are not saved. I see that you set `subscribe_depth` to false, no depth images will be saved. I would not use `subscribe_scan_cloud` for the camera cloud, but `subscribe_scan` to get the fake laser scan you generated from the depth image. Your example seems similar to this [one](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry_.2B-_2D_laser): when subscribing to a laser scan, you should pre-sync the images before rtabmap node using `rgbd_sync` node.

> Could not create clouds for 188
> node(s). The cache may not contain
> point cloud data. Try re-downloading
> the map.

In rtabmapviz, do "Edit->Download all clouds" to refresh the cache.
[image: image description]

If for some reasons rtabmapviz cannot call rtabmap service, you can open the database in rtabmap standalone, then export from there:

```
$ rtabmap ~/.ros/rtabmap.db
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeffHu7](https://answers.ros.org/users/39986/jeffhu7/) on 2020-02-06**:
It worked after I adapted a new launch file from the one you linked above! (Although I still have no idea why it didn't let me save before, despite being able to see the map in rtabmapviz.) Thank you so much!!